# Getting the vocabulary of Stanford's glove model

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

Does anyone knows if I can get all the vocabulary for the glove model?

I look to do the same thing that this guy does to BERT on this video [on 15:40]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zJW57aCBCTk&ab_channel=ChrisMcCormickAI

Answer (score 0):

The GloVe vectors and their vocabulary are simply distributed as (space-separated column) text files. On a Unix-derived OS, you can get the vocabulary with a command like:

`cut -f 1 -d ' ' glove.6B.50d.txt`

If you'd like to do it in Python, the following works. The only trick is that the files use no quoting. Rather, the GloVe files simply use space as a delimiter and space is not allowed inside tokens.

```
import csv
vocab = set()
with open("glove.6B.100d.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    g300 = csv.reader(f, delimiter=" ", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar=None)
    for row in g300:
        vocab.add(row[0])
print(vocab)
```